# "It looks like this app isn't available" Facebook App Login Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Need help with Facebook Login. When I try to log in and get an `acess_token` to work with the Facebook API, I get the error "It looks like this app isn't available".

[image]

And I can't find a clear answer why this error occurs.
The permissions I'm requesting from Facebook are: `pages_read_engagement`, `pages_show_list`

From different answers (including the one on Stack Overflow), I tried the following solutions:

1. "App ID" and "App Secret" are exactly correct (since everything works as it should from a developer account).
2. The app is in "Live" mode
3. `email` and `public_profile` permissions are set to advanced access
4. "App Domain" and "OAuth Redirect URIs" are configured correctly.
5. "Privacy Policy URL" and "Terms of Service URL"

Comment: _"The permissions I'm requesting from Facebook are: pages_read_engagement, pages_show_list"_ - and you did already get those reviewed & approved by Facebook?

Comment: No. I sent a request to App Review, but the App Review Team wrote back that they also had an error when authorizing via Facebook Login (http://joxi.ru/LmGWdKgsZpDg3m)

Comment: Then why are you trying to log in with non-developer accounts already (assuming that means normal user), if you have not gotten it reviewed yet?

Comment: Because the App Review team responded that they couldn't get through Facebook Login. I tried to log in with a normal user (not a developer), and I also got an error. Therefore, I decided that I first need to fix this error with authorization, and then re-submit it to App Review

Comment: Your screenshot from the previous comment doesn't load for me, so I don't know what exactly they said, what error they got.

Comment: App Review Team error feedback https://prnt.sc/1Fhl24D98w0B

Comment: On a side note, if you want to test the API calls before starting the implementation, you can use the Graph API Explorer tool to test the calls https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Make sure when you test your calls, the user account that you are testing with has a role in the app. You can add the user from the App Dashboard under "App Roles" tab. https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your_app_id_here}/roles/roles/

Comment: i'm getting the same error when i use normal user account `It looks like this app isn't available`
but i could submit my app, by switch it to development mode

Comment: Hi Vlad, did you find any solution to this problem? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 8):

i had the same problem although i did not made any changes in the app settings by myself, my Facebook Login was changed to Facebook Login for Businesses. I then followed the tutorial to create a Config in Sidepanel of the App -> Facebook Login for Businesses -> Configurations. You get a config_id which i appended to my existing query string i use for invoking a manual dialog. The string looks like this on my side:

`https://www.facebook.com/v17.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://XXXXXXX.COM&state=some_string&config_id=XXXXXXXXX`

after that i could successfully request an access_token

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using `Facebook Login For Business` instead of `Facebook login`.

In this case, you need to create a specific configuration and use it in your `FB Login Button`.

Full sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {  // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);                   // The current login status of the person.
    if (response.status === 'connected') {   // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
      testAPI();  
    } else {                                 // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this webpage.';
    }
  }


  function checkLoginState() {               // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // See the onlogin handler
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }


  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{app-id}',
      cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
      xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
      version    : 'v17.0'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
    });


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
      statusChangeCallback(response);        // Returns the login status.
    });
  };
 
  function testAPI() {                      // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }

</script>


<!-- The JS SDK Login Button -->

<fb:login-button 
  config_id="{configurationId}"
  onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

<!-- Load the JS SDK asynchronously -->
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well how do we use facebook login instead of facebook login for business?
Edit: nevermind, found answer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business/

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got this error because I was using `configId` instead of `config_id` on [Facebook Login for Business](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business/).

```js
FB.login(
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  {
    config_id: '<CONFIG_ID>' // right
    // configId: '<CONFIG_ID>' // wrong
  }
);
```

Comment: I believe the problem has to do with a change from "Facebook login" to "facebook login for business". If you are using a third party component like firebaseui switch back to facebook login like I did. It can be done at the top of the facebook login page, otherwise you can try the above solution. It may be a while before third parties make changes to support it.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue [image]

I tried everything but the problem is when I created an app previously "without verifying Business" Meta notify me to verify your business. after I verify the Business it still not working at last I archive and create a new app and it start working.

**Note:**

Don't archive the old app if you have important data in it. As I have not any data in that App that is why I archive

Comment: So it didn't work for you until you created a new app for it?

Comment: @TerryWindwalker yes correct I have to create a new app. I tried all the above solutions but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this error while using `python`, `django` , `django-allauth` and Facebook Login for Business then create configuration on **Facebook Login for Business > Configurations > Create Configuration**
After creating configuration you will have config_id to use in `settings.py`
After that add config_id in your facebook settings in SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS like below

```py
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    
    "facebook": {
        "METHOD": "oauth2",
        
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {
            "auth_type": "reauthenticate",
            # NOTE required for Facebook Login Business
            "config_id": FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FOR_BUSINESS_CONFIG_ID,
        },
        # ... others
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a WordPress theme that we purchased from Envato Market. Changing the app back from Facebook Business to Facebook Login fixed the issue. For whatever reason, my Facebook account could see the app in the Facebook (Meta) developers portal, but the change wouldn't stick when pressing the button to change back to Facebook Login -- even after entering a reason as to why we needed to switch back. The page would just say there. I reached out to the guy who handles all of our Facebook accounts and has the highest level of access and when he submitted the change, it went through... and then the login functionality worked on the WordPress site (tied to BuddyPress).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by switching the login from Facebook from Business back to Facebook Login (which had disappeared as an menu option previously)

Comment: It doesnt look like thats an option anymore. I think rolling back expires after 30 days. Was anyone able to solve this without rolling back to facebook login?

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it started working after adding `response_type=code` in auth URL.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `Facebook Login` to `Facebook Login for Businesses` for Business verification process. After Verification I forgot to changed it back to normal Facebook Login that's why I was facing this issue.
Changing it back to normal Facebook Login solved my issue