# Facebook Business Login: app not active: This app is not currently accessible and the app developer is aware of the issue

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm trying to use Facebook Login for Business to attempt and get a valid oauth token for an app I am building.

When I run through the flow myself, as the app owner, everything works perfectly. But anyone else gets the error in the title.

Things I have done to try and fix this:

- Ensured the app is in live mode
- Validated the business that this app is a part of (via the linked business page)
- Requested and received advanced permissions for profile data
- Created a login configuration and am using that in the request (thanks to ["It looks like this app isn't available" Facebook App Login Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75601813/it-looks-like-this-app-isnt-available-facebook-app-login-error) for that tip!)
- Completed the data use checkup

Is there anything else I can do to try and make sure this works?

Example of the url I am generating to redirect the user:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=<client id>&redirect_uri=<redacted>&scope=instagram_basic,pages_show_list,instagram_content_publish,pages_manage_posts,pages_read_engagement,business_management&response_type=code&state=<base64 encoded state object>&config_id=<valid login config id>
```

Comment: Did you contact the Facebook Developer Support?

Comment: I have, they haven't gotten back to me in several weeks. Was hoping StackOverflow might be faster... Though by contact, I mean I posted on the support forums. Is there a better way to get ahold of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did get this working. It's somewhat unclear how.

The only thing I did differently this time is after going live, I went to the Graph API tester (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and actually tried to generate an app-level token for my new app (I started the app from scratch).

And to be specific, I tried it before the app was live, got an error, then marked the app live. I want to be specific in the steps because I don't actually understand what caused this to work.

This caused me to go through the oauth flow with the same user as before (the one that always worked) but somehow after this other users were also able to go through the flow.

Could be that somehow this tells Facebook to mark the login configuration as active? Or maybe there was actually a bug and they fixed it in the time since I tried last.

Answer (score 0):

some office environtment are doesn't allow facebook to be accessed via their own network for productivity or something else reason.

so sorry for asking this, are you sure that your app network allow access to FB?

if still not really sure, i strongly recomend you to confirmate it to your IT network department to allow your app network, to get access to FB

thank you

Comment: Both myself and the other person trying to connect are on the same network, and it works fine for me.